# Finding the "expanded to factored" algorithm

Tags: algorithm, expansion, factorization

This question is about algorithms and thus language-independent.

---

Given the following rows:

- `A1, B1, C1, D1` *(1)*
- `A1, B2, C1, D1` *(2)*
- `A2, B1, C1, D1` *(3)*
- `A2, B2, C1, D1` *(4)*
- `A3, B1, C1, D1` *(5)*
- `A3, B2, C1, D1` *(6)*
- `A1, B1, C2, D1` *(7)*

They can be factored as follow:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 |
| A2 | B2 |    |    |
| A3 |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+
| A1 | B1 | C2 | D1 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

---

The following objects can store those data:

```
class ExpandedRow {
  String a;
  String b;
  String c;
  String d;
}

class FactoredRow {
  List<String> as;
  List<String> bs;
  List<String> cs;
  List<String> ds;
}
```

---

Concerning the transformations algorithms, the `factored --> expanded` one is quite easy:

```
List<FactoredRow> factoredRows = fill();
List<ExpandedRow> expandedRows = empty();
for each factoredRow in factoredRows {
  for each a in factoredRow.as {
    for each b in factoredRow.bs {
      for each c in factoredRow.cs {
        for each d in factoredRow.ds {
          expandedRows.add(new ExpandedRow(a, b, c, d));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm lost concerning the `expanded --> factored` one. How can I factorize a `List<ExpandedRow>` into a `List<FactoredRow>`?

In other words, I have the *factored table* as input. I expand it using the provided algorithm and store it in its *expanded* state. The question is: **how to retrieve the initial *factored* state after having expanding it?**

---

I thought that if two expanded rows have only one attribute that differs, they can be factored, for example `A1, B1, C1, D1` *(1)* and `A1, B1, C2, D1` *(2)*. But if we factorize those two rows together, we will end with:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 |
|    |    | C2 |    |
+----+----+----+----+
| A1 | B2 | C1 | D1 |
| A2 |    |    |    |
| A3 |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+
| A2 | B1 | C1 | D1 |
| A3 |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Which is *less factored* than the initial table.

It's seems that there are many factored solutions, and the main issue is to define and to find the *most factored* one.

Comment: I don't understand how your factorization work. Can you detail ?

Comment: Can the rows be permuted? Note that the first and the last row taken together can be factored in a nontrivial way. If the rows can be permutated, how to you specify which "factorization" you accept. Also -- to me it would seem more natural to say that rows 1-6 are being factored but that the overall list of rows is more akin to a prime number. - 7 doesn't *factor* as 3x2x1x1 + 1

Comment: @coincoin - OP seems to be trying to factor a set of vectors as a Cartesian product of lower dimensional sets of vectors.

Comment: @coincoin I have to admit that it isn't very clear... Here is the concrete use case: I have the *factorized table* as input. I expand it using the provided algorithm and store it in its expanded state. The question is: how to retrieve the initial *factorized* state?

Comment: @JohnColeman You must be right, it seems to me that there isn't *one* factorized state, but multiple factorized states. I would then need to find the *most factorized* one. The question is now: how to define the *most factorized* state, and how to build it. Maybe sorting the expanded rows in some way may help?

Comment: @sp00m My guess is that once you formulate it clearly you will be left with an NP-hard problem involving finding an optimal partition of a set of lists (optimal relative to a computationally expensive objective function). It's just a guess, and not terribly relevant if your intended application involves smallish collections of lists.

Comment: Similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281493/fuse-tuples-to-find-equivalence-classes

Comment: @sp00m What is wrong with the factorization A1 B1 {C1, C2} D1?

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle Actually, there is nothing wrong with it. It's just that if we factorize these two rows together, we'll end with 3 factorized filters: `A1 B1 {C1 C2} D1`, `{A1 A2 A3} B2 C1 D1` and `{A2 A3} B1 C1 D1`, which is *less factorized* than the initial factorized table.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems something like a graph partitioning problem. I suspect it's NP-hard but I haven't been able to prove it yet.

Let's take a simpler example to see what's going on. Consider the pairs `(A1,B1), (A2,B1), (A3,B1), (A2,B2)`. We represent the points as points in 2D-space, and connect points if it is possible to move from one to the other by a translation parallel to the x- or y-axis:

```
           (A2,B2)
              |
(A1,B1) -- (A2,B1) -- (A3,B1)
```

The idea is to partition the graph by lines parallel to the axes, and repartition each partition, and so on, until we get pieces that are complete rectangles, line segments, or points.

There are two esssentially different ways of partitioning the graph above.  We can draw a vertical line at position x=1.5:

```
           (A2,B2)
              |
(A1,B1)    (A2,B1) -- (A3,B1)
```

after which the right-side piece needs to be further partitioned (by a vertical or horizontal line, let's take horizontal):

```
           (A2,B2)

(A1,B1)    (A2,B1) -- (A3,B1)
```

We have now factored the original list into

```
A1 B1
-----
A2 B2
-----
A2 B1
A3
```

On the other hand, if we had made our initial partition with a horizontal line at position y=1.5, we would have

```
           (A2,B2)

(A1,B1) -- (A2,B1) -- (A3,B1)
```

which is already nicely factored into a point and a line segment:

```
A2 B2
-----
A1 B1
A2
A3
```

In higher dimensions (4D for letters A, B, C, D) we have a similar problem, except that there are correspondingly more choices for initial cuts, and the allowed final pieces are higher-dimesional (not just points, line segments, and rectangles but also 3D and 4D boxes).

The problem feels NP-hard to me, just like many other graph partitioning problems, but there are probably reasonably fast approximation algorithms.